# Copy selected files to zipped folder: Error "File not found or no read permission" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I have a code that zips all selected files(credits to RonDeBruin's code) though I revised some parts of it. My problem is that everytime I run the code it pops up an error like this: 
[image]

And here is my code:

```
Sub zipAllFiles()
 'rondebruin <--- Credits to code

Dim FileNameZip, FolderName
Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
Dim oApp As Object
Dim Fold As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Long

DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    DefPath = DefPath & "\"
End If

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row  '---> Files Directories

strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"


'Create empty Zip File
NewZip (FileNameZip)

'E3:E&lastrow  ---> Where the files directories are located.
For Each Fold In ws.Range("E3:E" & lastrow)
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    FolderName = Fold.Value
    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FolderName
Next Fold


ws.Range("J1").Value = Dir(FileNameZip) '---> The directory of the Zipped file to Range(J1).

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False


 End Sub
```

But when I debug it, it won't pop up any error. Is there something wrong with the code? Or should I make changes on the Folder or program settings? Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

If it works while debugging, but gives errors when not debugging, there may be a problem with the asynchronousness of your code. It seems to call (start) and external process that may not be finished when VB executes its next statement. So the library you are using (Ron de Bruin's, you refer to, which I don't have here) may include a function to wait for the process to be ready.

I also note:

```
For Each Fold In ws.Range("E3:E" & lastrow)
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

You seem to create a new shell with every iteration of the loop. Wouldn't creating it once before the loop be enough?